# Python beautiful Soup code not working

Tags: python, linux, beautifulsoup

I am trying this code in linux  and its giving empty output.
I have just coped and paste for BS docs

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""Bob's <b>Bold</b> Barbeque Sauce now available in
                        <b class="hickory">Hickory</b> and <b class="lime">Lime</a>""")

soup.find("b", { "class" : "lime" })
```

The output is empty

Comment: soup.find("b", { "class" : "lime" }).contents seems to be working just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script won't output anything unless you `print` it. You need...

```
print soup.find("b", { "class" : "lime" })
```

(This is working here.)

Comment: i tried similar thing like `for anchor in soup.findall('a',  { "class" : "active" } ):`
   `print anchor['href']` and it didn't work as well

Comment: Does the script you posted still output nothing if you add that `print`?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Python 2.6 or 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3.2.0.